# Добавить поле в массовый редактор товаров WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить поле поиска в массовое редактирование товаров WooCommerce? (поиск под категорией товаров)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: картинку вставляй в вопрос.

Comment: Форум запрещает прикреплять скриншоты к вопросам или что?

Comment: Какой-то форум может и нет, а вот правила SO гласят что картинки должна быть в вопросе. Да и здравый смысл должен подсказывать - "не создавай помогающим трудностей". Ну это если ты хочешь получить ответ, разумеется.